# How do I save Object back to the database with a null value for a date parameter?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a date picker on my WPF window that is optional. By that I mean there is no requirement to select a date before saving the Employee object back to the database. However I am having trouble getting the save to work when try to save it without the date set. The error is:

***SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.***

What am I doing wrong?

```
private DateTime _ExpectedPromotionDate;
public DateTime ExpectedPromotionDate
{
    get
    {
        return _ExpectedPromotionDate;
    }
    set
    {
        DateTime temp;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(_ExpectedPromotionDate), out temp))
        {
            _ExpectedPromotionDate = value;
        }
        else
        {
            _ExpectedPromotionDate = DBNull.Value;
            //throw new ApplicationException("Promotion Date is mandatory.");
        }
    }
}
```

By the way my save function looks like this

```
public bool Save()
{
    try
    {
        Dac.ExecuteNonQuery("Manpower_InsertEmployee",
            Dac.Parameter(CN_LoginId, LoginId),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_StoreId, StoreId),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_FirstName, FirstName),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_LastName, LastName),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_EeRole, EeRole),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_RoleRank, RoleRank),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_IsUpNComing, IsUpNComing),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_ExpectedPromoDate, ExpectedPromotionDate),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_IsPotentialManager, IsPotentialManager));
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        //throw new Exception (String.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
        throw new Exception("There was an error during the save process.");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the database definition of the column? Does it allow nulls? When you do not select a date, what does `_ExpectedPromotionDate` evaluate to?

Comment: Does your: `_ExpectedPromotionDate = DBNull.Value;` throw an exception, I would think you would get an exception here.

Comment: The database does allow nulls and for good measure I added a default value to that parameter. The _expectedPromotionDate evaluates to: parameterValue {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}. The DBNull.Value doesn't compile so I don't even get the opportunity to see it throw the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime is not nullable.

DateTime? is nullable. (Or Nullable< Datetime> if you prefer that syntax)
Make sure your caller sets this value to null if there is no value selected by the user.

```
private DateTime? _ExpectedPromotionDate;
public DateTime? ExpectedPromotionDate
{
    get
    {
        return _ExpectedPromotionDate;
    }
    set
    {

            _ExpectedPromotionDate = value;

    }
}






Dac.Parameter(CN_ExpectedPromoDate, ExpectedPromotionDate??(object)DbNull.Value),
```

Answer (score 3):

A Sql DateTime column cannot represent all possible .NET DateTime values. I suspekt your UI picker is returning DateTime.MinValue, which cannot be represented in a SQL DateTime.

SQL DateTime has valid values from `1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM` and `12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM` (as indicated by the error message) while .NET DateTime has valid values from `01-01-0001 00:00:00`
 to `31-12-9999 23:59:59`.

Also, your guard clause in the setter does not make sense, you are parsing the value you already have, and if it succeeds, you set the field to `value`. Also, setting a `DateTime` field to `DBNull.Value` is a compile error. I don't know the exact types involved in your scenario, but I suspect you want something like this in the setter:

```
if (value >= SqlDateTime.MinValue && value < SqlDateTime.MaxValue) 
    _ExpectedPromotionDate = value;
else 
    _ExpectedPromotionDate = DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

That code won't compile I don't think. The DateTime type is not compatible with DBNull. Try something like this? Also make sure the column in your database is nullable.

```
private DateTime? _ExpectedPromotionDate;
public DateTime? ExpectedPromotionDate
{
    get
    {
        return _ExpectedPromotionDate;
    }
    set
    {
         _ExpectedPromotionDate = value;
    }


}

public bool Save()
{
    try
    {
        Dac.ExecuteNonQuery("Manpower_InsertEmployee",
            Dac.Parameter(CN_LoginId, LoginId),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_StoreId, StoreId),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_FirstName, FirstName),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_LastName, LastName),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_EeRole, EeRole),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_RoleRank, RoleRank),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_IsUpNComing, IsUpNComing),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_ExpectedPromoDate, ExpectedPromotionDate.HasValue ? ExpectedPromotionDate.Value : DBNull.Value),
            Dac.Parameter(CN_IsPotentialManager, IsPotentialManager));
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        //throw new Exception (String.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
        throw new Exception("There was an error during the save process.");

    }
```